# AS3 BitmapData to byteArray

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to serialize a Bitmap to store in an XML file. My plan is to turn the BitmapData into a byteArray, but I haven't been able to fine an example of this.

Other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: What about base64 encoding the image data?  Why do you want to include the image data in an XML file to begin with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process should be: BitmapData > ByteArray > Base64 > XML

Use the BitmapData getPixels() method to get a ByteArray of the pixels.

Then you can use something like [Hurlant's Base64](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/source/browse/trunk/as3crypto/src/com/hurlant/util/Base64.as) encoder to convert it to base 64.

Then going the other way, "unbase64" it, then use BitmapData's setPixels to load it.

Comment: +1. Although it was not mentioned in the question, I wouldn't store the raw pixels. PNG would be a good fit here if the image data is going to be compressed and decompressed back and forth (using PNGEncoder from adobe as 3 lib for compressing and Loader.loadBytes for decompressing).