# how to change shared object path when I save data in it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

how to change `sharedObject` save location,I want to save shared object on server for particular user, what I do for this?

Comment: Do you have a Flash Media server? or you use DB?

Comment: anyone can short out my problem....

Comment: SharedObject.getLocal("save","i'm not able to give path here"); if so my prob will be solved...

Comment: i asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084338/sharedobject-location

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [`SharedObject.getRemote()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getRemote%28%29) if you have a Flash Media server. Alternatively you can encode the data associated with your `SharedObject` as JSON and store it in a database.

Comment: thanks mr.marty,but My sharedobject contains image and similar types data. so will it be able to encode in JSON?

Comment: @dev Depends how you're linking the image to the SharedObject. Do you mean that you're assigning a Bitmap to the data?

Comment: @dev You can convert the image into data that can be stored. [See here for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349019/as3-bitmapdata-to-bytearray). Still I would probably try find alternate ways of doing this.

Comment: so if i save image in bytearray.. will JSON file strore this data? I think JSON file store strings more accurately ...

Comment: What @MartyWallace suggests is that you should not use a SharedObject or an LSO to store an image or large data. Look for alternatives like a db or filesystem by encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

Bad way, but it works

```
var src:ByteArray = your byteArray;

var arr:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < src.length; i++)
{
    arr.push(src.readByte());
}
var jsonStr:String = arr.join("|");
```

and conversely...

```
var retArr:Array = jsonStr.split("|");
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
for (var j:int = 0; j < retArr.length; j++)
{
    ba.writeByte(retArr[j]);
}

var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
ldr.loadBytes(ba);
addChild(ldr);
```