# Using filereference to save game data

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm creating a game where I'm using sharedobject to save data.  I would like to give the players the option to choose where to save their file to.  Is there a way to use filereference to accomplish this?

Here's an example of the code:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("savedata");

var playerHealth:Number = 10;
var playerStamina:Number = 4;
var playerCash:Number = 4;

//Save Function
function saveData(e:MouseEvent):void{
    saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerHealth = playerHealth;
    saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerStamina = playerStamina;
    saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerCash = playerCash;
    saveDataObject.flush();
    }

//Load Function
function loadData(e:MouseEvent):void{
    playerHealth = saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerHealth;
    playerStamina = saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerStamina;
    playerCash = saveDataObject.data.savedPlayerCash;
    }
```

Comment: Here is a post, I think it would help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084338/sharedobject-location

Comment: Thank you, that post helped a lot.